# What does a single dot in a file path mean?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, filepath

I'm using the Informatica Secure Agent which has a script that sets `JAVA_HOME` to the following path:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Informatica Cloud Secure Agent\apps\agentcore\.\..\..\jre
```

I'm familar with the fact that `..` means to go up a directory but I'm unsure what the `.` after `\agentcore\` means.

Is it redundant or could it even set a wrong path?

Comment: ``.\`` means current directory. Inside your file path it is absolutely useless, but not harmful. See the Microsoft article [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file).

Comment: Useless but not harmful, right? The dot does not substitute the path, so the path is somehow set twice?

Comment: The absolute path without all relative parts can be determined in a batch file by running `for %%I in ("%JAVA_HOME%") do set "JAVA_HOME=%%~fI"` which redefines environment variable `JAVA_HOME` as `C:\Program Files\Informatica Cloud Secure Agent\jre`. I recommend to do that in your batch file because having real absolute path of files and folders is always helpful when an error occurs on execution of a batch script.

Comment: Note that in Windows, "." and ".." components are resolved by the system runtime library before passing the path to the kernel I/O manager and file system. This is very different from Unix with respect to reparse points (e.g. symlinks and junction mountpoints). Note also that a filename with a leading "." or ".." component is not a relative filename in the context of `SearchPath`. For example, it looks for ".\\spam.txt" only in the current directory, while it looks for "spam.txt" in the given search path (and even "eggs\\spam.txt", unlike Unix).

Comment: duplicate: [What are "." and ".." in a directory?](https://superuser.com/q/37449/241386)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I know that a single dot means the current directory, I'm wondering **why** that is something that is done by the official installation script.